# Does the compiler move static definitions out of loops?

Tags: python-3.x

Let's say I have this loop with a definition in it:

```
for name in ["alice", "bob", "ceelo"]:
     full_name = name + {"alice": "cooper", "bob": "dylan", "ceelo":"green"}[name]
     print(full_name)
```

As you can see, my dict isn't assigned to anything. I could save runtime by refractoring it to:

```
names = {"alice": "cooper", "bob": "dylan", "ceelo":"green"}
for name in names:
     full_name = name + names[name]
```

... but I don't want to. For reasons. I promise.

My question: **Does the standard Python compiler automatically perform this refractor?**

Comment: Python isn’t compiled. And please let us know what you want to archive.

Answer (score 0):

First, python does not use a compiler because there is no compiled file generated after you try to run some python files, it uses interpreter.

Here even if you do not assign the dict to any variable name e.g.
"names = {"alice": "cooper", "bob": "dylan", "ceelo":"green"}", the dictionary itself is still a dictionary and it occupies some space in your memory, no matter a name given or not.

Therefore
, you will be able to use key to get your value e.g. "{"alice": "cooper", "bob": "dylan", "ceelo":"green"}[name]". But the python interpreter will not assign the dictionary to a variable automatically if you never declare so.